# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on bool

Tags: plugins, php

I am getting the error when trying to execute my wp plugin:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-database\vragen_plugin.php:784

The code in question is here

```
// Create question function
function create_question_function(){

// Make database connection
    global $dbname, $link;    
    mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname) or die("Could not open the db '$dbname'");

// Grab email from Wordpress    
    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $email = (string) $current_user->user_email;

// Check for admin mail
    $admin_mail = $link->query("SELECT * FROM proxydb");
    while ($rowadm = $admin_mail->fetch_array()) {
        if ($rowadm[1] == $email){
            $admin = '1';
        } 
    }

// If ur an admin, you have access to the following page
    if($admin == '1'){
```

Comment: The message is quite clear: `$admin_mail` is a boolean, as indicated by the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/).

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$admin_mail` is **not an array** (or array of results). It is returning `false` probably which is a `boolean` value.

Your query `'Select * from proxydb'` is returning `false`. Please check if you really have records in the database for the table `proxydb` OR the the table name is really without `wp_` or **other prefix** defined at the time of table definition?